# Name a CSS file as principal

Tags: css

Is there a standard way to name a CSS file as being principal? I have two CSS files (one for Bootstrap and one for my custom CSS) and I want all styles from the custom file to be taken as important for all the project's files. But I also want to keep the Bootstrap. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS specification stipulates that selector precedence is subject to three factors, in order:

1. Importance
2. Specificity
3. Source order

Although there is no way to define a stylesheet as principal, what you might be looking at is source order. Style rules that come further in the order will take precedence. Therefore, import your custom stylesheet after the bootstrap stylesheet and rules in the former might take precedence, depending on importance and specificity defined in the later. More info about cascading preference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance).

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to use something like `index.html` so the browser understand it must load it first when you tipe `www.example.com/`, then no; there is no name rules for css files. The most common name is `style.css`.

Here is what you can do: first load your bootstrap files in your html

```
<link href="css/bootsrap.css">
```

After that, load your custom css file. Now, sometimes when you try to overwrite the rules of boostrap will not work, so u can use the `!important` clause before closing your declaration, like this:

```
background-color: red !important
```

Comment: `!important` should be avoided at all costs. Instead they should create selectors with greater specificity.

Comment: @j08691 I wouldn't say to avoid it at ALL costs. There are valid use cases, like a utility `.red` or `.bold` class that you want to always override other classes; those are the kind of uses `!important` is intended for. What one should avoid is abusing `!important` when it's not actually necessary.